# How to clear the list of recently used files to speed up my lubuntu operated PC?

Tags: lubuntu

From where can I find out the list of recently used files in lubuntu? Can I see the cache files / clipboard in lubuntu likewise in Windows?

Comment: How exactly do you think cleaning the cache, that the system will build again, will speed your equip? What are your equip specs? Please consider EDIT your question.

Comment: I am not an expert guy in Ubuntu. I am sorry to say that I don't know what are my equip specs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will speed up your PC but here's how you do it:

```
$ rm ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```